# My server cant resolve domains?

Tags: domain-name-system

I am on a VPS that is pretty much unmanaged so it means im on my own. I did my best to configure it so i can host my own site for other people to see it online but seems like i have network problems because in the last days many of my users report they cant enter my site from my domain and seems like Google and Facebook cant either (this never happened before).

Its weird because i can enter my site without problems and so many other people as well. But then i tried to make a php include and i get this error:

```
Warning: include(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in
```

I was told that seems like my server cant resolve domains. The includes work if i use IPs instead of domains. So it means i have a DNS problem or something? What can i do to fix it? Im on a Linux 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 on x86_64 CentOS Linux 6.5

Thank you.

EDIT:

i have this on my resolv.conf

```
# Generated by NetworkManager


# No nameservers found; try putting DNS servers into your
# ifcfg files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts like so:
#
# DNS1=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DNS2=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DOMAIN=lab.foo.com bar.foo.com


nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: What's in your /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: I edited my question with that info. Please check it back.

Comment: Can you try that again, copying and pasting from a command line session and not from some GUI or web interface. It's impossible to tell what's in the file and what isn't. And use the markup for code to ensure it's formatted properly here.

Comment: I did my best but i cant get it without the bold. Sorry. However i think the important part is below that since everything else is commented out.

Comment: What did you put in the `include()` that gave you that error message?

Comment: A page of my own domain, but then i tried with sites such as yahoo.com and i got the same error. However, with the IP works just fine.

Comment: Help please?????

Comment: Is the file named `resolv.conf` or `resolve.conf`? The correct name has no second `e`.

Comment: Why are you putting hostnames and IPs in `include`? While it's possible to get include files from the network, it's an unusual thing to do. Usually you just include local files.

Comment: I just mistyped, the file is correct. Also, i only tested the include like that in order to see if i have a dns problem which i do and its what i need to fix. Can you help me with that please?

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like all symptoms are pointing at a problem with the authoritative DNS servers for the domain rather than a problem with the server itself.

Looking up the domain name, I find that on the `.com` servers it is delegated to `ns29.domaincontrol.com` and `ns30.domaincontrol.com`. There are glue records (but only for IPv4), and the IP addresses of those two DNS servers are not in the same `/8`. Both DNS servers reply with the same `A` record, and both are able to report no `AAAA` record for the domain.

The domain would be unreachable to IPv6-only users, but that is probably not the problem you are facing. At this point I am wondering if you might have two different problems, and the symptoms you see from your own server is caused by something other than the reachability problems, seen from outside.

I looked up the IP address of the server, and found it to be announced by [AS16276](http://bgp.he.net/AS16276). That network has a large number of peers, so having no route at all to that network, does not sound like the most likely explanation. It does however mean there are more different paths packets could get routed to your server, and more possibilities for problems affecting a small number of users. (That is sort of a good thing, because you don't want outages to affect all your users). With this knowledge, the next I would look for is traceroute from some of the affected users towards your server as well as traceroute output from your server towards the IP address of those clients.

There is a warning about bogons being announced by AS16276. But it is not related to the IP address of your server, so I don't think that is a problem. I tested traceroute towards your IP from three different networks in two different countries, and I saw no reachability problems. I saw a few routers on the way, which would rarely send time exceeded messages, but that in itself is no problem.

Comment: So its something i cant fix my self nor my host?

Comment: @Nuker If you want an answer, you need to give us the information we need. We can't guess what your domain name is, and you haven't told us, what problem your DNS provider has.

Comment: Thats kinda sensitive information. Can I tell you by PM or something?

Comment: @Nuker The point of serverfault is that others with the same problem can lookup the answer, which in this case would include the steps involved in debugging. So the answer would include the domain name. Be aware that when somebody try to reach your site, the domain name is sent in clear over the Internet. If the domain name itself is sensitive, then you should really focus on fixing the systems which assumed a domain name could be kept secret.

Comment: Okay, here you go: saintseiyaforos.net i would appreciate your help. I tried all and im getting out of ideas.

Comment: Help please????

Comment: @Nuker Have you read the updated answer? Have you checked traceroute outputs?

Comment: Sorry, i hadnt seen it. I want to do as you suggest but im still looking for any available users i can ask them to do that. So what solution you suggest in the mean time?

Comment: @Nuker Look at the network traffic. If any of them can send you a SYN packet, but cannot make a request and get a response, then you have a starting point for further investigation. If they can send a SYN but not receive a SYN-ACK, you should occasionally see sockets in state `SYN_RECV` for a few minutes. If the handshake completes but the connection stalls later, it will look differently.

Comment: I got somebody who says cant access. Should i ask him to perform a nslookup at my domain?